# Using selenium: How to keep logged in after closing Driver using python

Tags: python, selenium

not need to log in chrome driver each time i open new window in chrome driver using selenium

```py
options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\oyo\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
```

```sh
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of a way doing this, except when using cookies.

`driver.manage().addCookie(arg0)`